# Is it possible to extract everyday stock closing price in Python and store them to Excel?

Tags: python, excel, yahoo-finance, trading, google-finance

Is it possible to extract closing prices of stock market and dynamically write them into an excel sheet using python?

**Example:**
Can I get `GOOG`, `AAPL`, `MSFT`, `AMZN` everyday closing stock prices from Google-Finance or Yahoo!-Finance and write them automatically into an excel sheet?

Comment: Yes, this sounds quite possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far didn't manage to write any code yet. Looking for some solutions online, I will get back to you when something I start  @jdgregson

Comment: You can also try Query Tables to fetch tables from web pages directly into an Excel sheet. Take a look at this tutorial to get started: https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/query-table.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is pretty simple to write a program to do this in python. Here are the basic tools you'll need:

**Web scraper to get financial data**

- requests  and  BeautifulSoup

**Writing data to Excel file**

- pandas

You can find some nice tutorials online to get you started.